# Application_BeginRequest not firing on WebForms URL Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, webforms

Debugging through my application. ASP.NET WebForms 2.0 using URL routing. I'm registering my routes in Application_Start, however I'm noticing that my Application_BeginRequest method in Global.asax is not getting hit when requesting a routed URL versus the exact URL (i.e. with the .aspx file type).

Any ideas?

EDIT: IIS7 and the URLRoutingModule is in the web.config

Cheers,
-Steve

Comment: Is this on IIS? Did you update your Web.config to register the routing module?

Comment: Sorry, edited original post to have this info.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm having the same issue - I set up my routes in my .NET 3.5 WebForms app inside the Application_Start method, and Application_BeginRequest will not fire for any of those routes; it only fires for requests to the actual aspx pages.

Comment: Nick, I can't recall. I was combing through my SVN commits, but I can't find anything in particular regarding this. I'll keep looking.